# can use package interactively, but Rscript gives errors

Tags: r, topic-modeling, rscript

I'm using the "topicmodels" package in R. Everything works fine interactively, but if I run the exact same commands using `Rscript`, I get errors.

The first error (which I solved) is that R didn't know what the `is()` function was. I solved this by importing the `"methods"` package. Apparently, `Rscript` doesn't import this automatically, even though interactive R does, and this caused a problem with is(). Problem solved.

However, I am now stuck at a different error, which I can't figure out. I am using the `LDA()` function in the `"topicmodels"` package, using data (in DTM format) and k=10. I call it like this:

```
library(plyr)
library(lda)
library(topicmodels)
x = as.data.frame(sapply(1:100, function(x) sample(1:100,100,replace=T)))
u = llply(colnames(x), function(a) rbind(0:(length(x[,a])-1),x[,a]))
v = rownames(x)
y = ldaformat2dtm(u, v)
a = LDA(x, 10)
```

And it gives me the following error:

```
> Error in as(control, "LDA_VEMcontrol") :
>   no method or default for coercing "NULL" to "LDA_VEMcontrol"
> Calls: LDA -> method -> as
> Execution halted
```

The main thing is this works interactively, but not using `Rscript`. I know the data is correctly formatted and if I print the data, it looks good. Is there something else I'm missing? Are there other modules that `Rscript` doesn't load, but R interactive does load? Thanks!

Comment: Since you haven't provided `x` to us perhaps you were remiss in providing it to R as well.

Comment: can i attach a 500 mb file? anyway, my question is about Rscript vs. R interactive. is there a way to run Rscript EXACTLY like R interactive?

Comment: No use a subset using `dput(head(x, 15))` and make sure this gives the error as well.

Comment: Ok, something like this should work: library(plyr); library(lda); library(topicmodels); x = as.data.frame(sapply(1:100, function(x) sample(1:100,100,replace=T))); u = llply(colnames(x), function(a) rbind(0:(length(x[,a])-1),x[,a])); v = rownames(x); y = ldaformat2dtm(u, v); tm = LDA(x, 10);

Comment: Ok so made an R script using your exact code and then named it `test.R` and used `source("test.R")` and it ran.  and `tm` is `A LDA_VEM topic model with 10 topics.` so are you using source?  I didn't have to import methods.  What are the error messages you get.  Please post them in your original question with code tags.

Answer (score 2):

I just ran the example via `Rscript` and via `source()` in an interactive session, both worked.  The only output from `Rscript` was:

```
% Rscript /tmp/sc.r
Loading required package: methods
```

So it seems to have figured out the `methods` thing on its own.

I have R 3.0.1, maybe you have an older version of R or one of the packages?  They may have updated their prereqs list to include `methods`.